# Plotting box plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm using the weather.csv dataset that comes with Rattle (NOTE: I'm NOT using Rattle for this) and trying to construct a box plot relating the wind direction and wind speed. I'm doing the following but no plot shows up and no errors or warnings either:

```
weatherPlot <- ggplot(weather, aes(factor(WindGustDir), WindGustSpeed)) 
weatherPlot + geom_boxplot()
```

Any ideas why my plot would be blank?

P.S. WindGustDir data is categorical values like N, E, W, S, NW, SE, etc and WindGustSpeed is numerical.

Comment: Try to `print()` the result of the last line.

Comment: @mbq that would only be relevant if the OP were running R non-interactively or if the code is inside a loop or similar where auto-printing is turned off.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Well, judging from acceptance this was likely the case.

Comment: @mbq I guess that's why a full, reproducible example is desired.

Comment: Actually the issue was that my code was perfect but the results were appearing in another window I couldn't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me on my installation (R 2.15.2, 64 bit.) So this probably isn't a coding thing. Can you check that you don't have any other code around this segment that is causing a problem (e.g. just try the minimalist code below.)

```
library(rattle)
library(ggplot2)

weatherPlot <- ggplot(weather, aes(factor(WindGustDir), WindGustSpeed)) 
weatherPlot + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]